# Adding negative lookback to this regex pattern in php

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, regex-lookarounds

I have spent the entire day trying to figure out how to get this code to only affect the first instance it runs across. Eventually, I learned about a negative lookback and tried to implement that.

I have tried every possible arrangement except, of course, the correct one.I discovered regex101, which is really cool, but ultimately didn’t help me find the solution.

```
$content = preg_replace('/<img[^>]+./','', get_the_content_with_format());
```

This will be used in wordpress to strip out the first image on a page (moving it above the written content), but leave the rest in so that there can be images used in the post description.

Be easy on me, please. This is my first question here and I really am not a programmer.

**Update:** Because l’L'l asked, this is the entire chunk of relevant code.

```
<?php
//this will remove the images from the content editor
// it will not remove links from images, so if an image has a link, you will end up with an empty line.

$content = preg_replace('/<img[^>]+./','', get_the_content_with_format());

//this IF statement checks if $content has any value left after the images were removed
// If so, it will echo the div below it.. if not will won't do anything.

if($content != ""):?>

        <div class="portfolio-box">
        <?php echo do_shortcode( $content ) ?>
        </div>

<?php endif; ?>
```

I’ve tried both of the solutions offered here but, for whatever reason, they didn’t work.

And, thank you guys very much for helping, by the way.

Comment: Add the string you are trying to manipulate to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You could just anchor it at the beginning of the string (with `^`), capture everything up to the first image (with `(.*?)`), and replace all of that with the content before the image:

```
$content = preg_replace('/^(.*?)<img[^>]+/s','$1', get_the_content_with_format());
```

Note I also added the modifier `s` so that dot (`.`) matches newlines.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to replace the first occurence of the regex match, just add "1" as fourth parameter, which indicates, that only one match will be replaced.
See http://php.net/manual/de/function.preg-replace.php

In your example, this would look like:

```
$content = preg_replace('/<img[^>]+./','', get_the_content_with_format(), 1);
```